# Bootstrap3 dropdown submenu is always open

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I'm creating submenu dropdown following this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_events2&stacked=h

but all my submenu are always open, I want it to work normally, which means the submenu will show only when I hover on the parent menu, i'm using bootstrap 3.3.7.

This is the description image, when I press the "CLICK" button the submenu is also always open (menu 3 and menu 4)
[image]

This is my code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">CLICK
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 1</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 3</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 3.1</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 4</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 4.1</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 4.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>


// style
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use display:none and then on hover display:block

```css
// style
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">CLICK
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 1</a></li>
                          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 2</a></li>
                          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 3</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 3.1</a></li>
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 3.2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 4</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 4.1</a></li>
                              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MENU 4.2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```